# Upload PDF file in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I try to upload a file in symfony form, but i get this error :Notice: Undefined index: file which mean it didn't recover the file.

My form :

```
<?php
namespace Polytech\SkillsBundle\Form\Rapport;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ButtonType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\FileType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\HiddenType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;

class FicheOccasionType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('ues', EntityType::class,
                array(
                    'class' => 'Polytech\SkillsBundle\Entity\UE',
                    'attr' => array('class' => 'browser-default ue'),
                    'choice_label' => 'nom',
                    'label' => false,
                    'required' => false,
                    'placeholder' => 'Choisissez une UE'
                )
            )
            ->add('etudiants', EntityType::class,
                array(
                    'class' => 'Polytech\SkillsBundle\Entity\Utilisateur',
                    'attr' => array('class' => 'browser-default etudiants'),
                    'choice_label' => 'nom',
                    'label' => false,
                    'required' => false,
                    'placeholder' => 'Choisissez un utilisateur'
                )
            )
            ->add('file', FileType::class, array('label' => 'PDF File'))
            ->add('submit', HiddenType::class)
            ->add('export', ButtonType::class, array('label' => 'Exporter'))
            ->add('import', ButtonType::class, array('label' => 'Import'));

    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'fiche_occasion';
    }
}
```

and this is my controller  (the important part ) :

```
 if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid() ) {
        $data = $request->request->get('fiche_occasion');
        $use = $data['ues'];
        $etudiants = $data['etudiants'];
        $file = $data['file'];
        $filename = md5(uniqid()).'.'.$file->guessExtension();
        $action = $data['submit'];
```

How I can retrieve the file information for the purpose of storing it in the web and storing its path in the database

Comment: Where did the error occur?

Comment: I get the error when i click in import or export button but this is not the problem because i can get  all  the information in the two cases i can get the $etudiants information and the $use but not the file

Comment: in this line   $file = $data['file'];

Comment: In the generated form, check if it is being set as a "POST" rather then "GET" and also make sure that the form has an `enctype="multipart/form-data"` property

Comment: also try getting the file like this $form->get('file')

Comment: The symfony documentation shows an example for [uploading a PDF](http://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/upload_file.html)

Comment: I tried this and it works  $file = $request->files->get('file');   Thank you !!

Answer (score 1):

Files are not stored in post or get vars. Files are stored in $request->files.

symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation.html#accessing-request-data

Try with $file = $request->files['file']; instead.

Comment: but i don't understand why the type is not UploadedFile ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to follow this link:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/upload_file.html

which contains a good practice (also security) to create form with *Upload File*.

In your case try to use `$ficheOccasion` *(your object....)*:

```
$ficheOccasion = new FicheOccasion(); // Your Entity Class (?)
$form = $this->createForm(FicheOccasionType::class, $ficheOccasion);
```

and Symfony do the job after this line in controller:

```
$form->handleRequest($request);
```

and after:

```
if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid() ) {
....
```

you probably have access to file content by:

```
$file = $ficheOccasion->getFile();
```

so you can do this:

```
$file->guessExtension();
$file->move( .... )
```

and on the end before persist the object to database:

```
$ficheOccasion->setFile($fileName); // your prepared filename...
```

Comment: Precisely I really need this way of working but I just have a question to start with symfony. The teaching unit that is an entity, studying it another entity ... and the evaluation sheet which is also another entity. Each student has several files and each file is for a single student. So $fiche = new Fiche(); // Your Entity Class (?)
$form = $this->createForm(Fiche::class, $fiche); create only Fiche entity with the file ??

Comment: i posted the probleme here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43001978/upload-pdf-file-with-symfony with details

Comment: I tried to change ficheOccasion with FichePDF which is my entity , i get this error : Neither the property "ues" nor one of the methods "getUes()", "ues()", "isUes()", "hasUes()", "__get()" exist and have public access in class "Polytech\SkillsBundle\Entity\FichePDF".