# Upload PDF file with symfony

Tags: php, symfony, pdf

I need a help on how to upload a pdf file in symfony. In general, the relationship between the student and the pdf card is as follows: A single student can have several pdf cards and one card for a single student. The entity sheet is as follows:

```
class FichePDF
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="Nom", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $nom;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     *
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Please, upload the evaluation file as a PDF file.")
     * @Assert\File(mimeTypes={ "application/pdf" })
     */
    private $file;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="Path", type="string", length=255)
     */


    private $path;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Polytech\SkillsBundle\Entity\Utilisateur", inversedBy="fichesPdf")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     *
     */
    private $etudiant;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Polytech\SkillsBundle\Entity\SousOccasion")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="ssocc_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */

    private $ssocc;
```

With getters and setters of course. For the student entity I added this line

```
/**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Polytech\SkillsBundle\Entity\FichePDF" , mappedBy="etudiant", cascade={"remove"})
     */

    private $fichesPdf;
```

I have a form that retrieves information about several entities in my application such as teaching units, exams and students and then retrieves a pdf file.

```
<?php
namespace Polytech\SkillsBundle\Form\Rapport;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ButtonType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\FileType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\HiddenType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;

class FicheOccasionType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('ues', EntityType::class,
                array(
                    'class' => 'Polytech\SkillsBundle\Entity\UE',
                    'attr' => array('class' => 'browser-default ue'),
                    'choice_label' => 'nom',
                    'label' => false,
                    'required' => false,
                    'placeholder' => 'Choisissez une UE'
                )
            )
            ->add('etudiants', EntityType::class,
                array(
                    'class' => 'Polytech\SkillsBundle\Entity\Utilisateur',
                    'attr' => array('class' => 'browser-default etudiants'),
                    'choice_label' => 'nom',
                    'label' => false,
                    'required' => false,
                    'placeholder' => 'Choisissez un utilisateur'
                )
            )
            ->add('file', FileType::class, array('label' => 'PDF File'))
            ->add('submit', HiddenType::class)
            ->add('export', ButtonType::class, array('label' => 'Exporter'))
            ->add('import', ButtonType::class, array('label' => 'Import'));

    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'fiche_occasion';
    }
}
```

How can I retrieve the file as Uploaded file and add it to the database. I read the documentation and it's not exactly what I do. Can you please help me

Answer (score 2):

You are halfway there as is described in the Documentation:

https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/upload_file.html

The following steps you already did:

1. Adding the property to your entity
2. Adding the upload element to the form

Now you have to handle the uploaded file and add the upload path to the entity. In your controller where you handle the form you now have to do the following:

```
$fiche = new FichePDF();
$form = $this->createForm(FichePDF::class, $fiche);
$form->handleRequest($request);

if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
    $file = $fiche->getFile();
    // Generate a unique name for the file before saving it
    $fileName = md5(uniqid()).'.'.$file->guessExtension();
    // Move the file to the directory where brochures are stored
    $file->move(
        $this->getParameter('upload_directory'),
        $fileName
    );
    // Update the 'fichePDF' property to store the PDF file name
    // instead of its contents
    $fiche->setFile($fileName);

    // Persist $fichePDF and do whatever else you want to
}
```

Comment: this code $fiche = new FichePDF();
$form = $this->createForm(FichePDF::class, $fiche);  return this error : Neither the property "ues" nor one of the methods "getUes()", "ues()", "isUes()", "hasUes()", "__get()" exist and have public access in class "Polytech\SkillsBundle\Entity\FichePDF . because the form return the id of ues entity ...

Comment: Ah, your form is not tied to the entity. In that case you can leave out the entity and instead of `$file = $fiche->getFile()` you have to do something like `$form->get('file')->getData()` to get the filename

Comment: Alternatively you could follow the docs more closely and create a form for that entity (see the link in my answer).